# Use SED to fix new lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a utf-16 file where each new line somehow have been replaced by `0x00 0x00 0x0A`. This make the file completely corrupt, and I try to use the sed command to replace this sequence with `0x00 0x0A`.

I have try to use following sed command, but it don't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
sed -i.bak 's/\x0\x0\0x0A/\x0\x0A/g' "test.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match `\x0A` as that is is `\n`, which can be matched using `$`.

Following should work in gnu-sed:

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/\x0\x0$/\x0/' test.h
```